# Problema com full outer join fazendo o filtro com o where

Tags: sql, firebird, join, firebird-2.5

Amigos,

Tenho um banco de dados com as seguintes tabelas:

**tipos**

```
id | nome
1  | Duplo
2  | Triplo
```

**disponibilidade**

```
    data   | tipo | ocupado | manutencao | referencia
01/03/2018 | 1    | 1       | 0          | 54684
01/03/2018 | 1    | 0       | 1          | 4525
01/03/2018 | 1    | 1       | 0          | 54686
```

Gostaria de fazer uma *query* que retornasse os seguintes dados:

```
   data    | nome   | ocupado | manutencao 
01/03/2018 | Duplo  | 2       | 1
01/03/2018 | Triplo | 0       | 0
```

Fiz a *query* abaixo só que não me retornou os dados da tabela **tipos**, descobri que só não retorna o resultado que quero quando faço o filtro pelas datas.

```
SELECT
d.data,
t.nome,
COALESCE(SUM(ocupado),0) ocupado,
COALESCE(SUM(manutencao),0) manutencao
FROM disponibilidade d
FULL OUTER JOIN tipos t ON d.tipo = t.id
WHERE d.data between '03-01-2018' AND '03-05-2018'
GROUP BY d.data, t.nome
```

Fiz este [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a30c3/2) para verificarem a estrutura do banco de dados.

Como utilizar o join de uma forma que dê para fazer o filtro de datas com o WHERE e me retorne o resultado que preciso?

Answer (score 0):

Do modo como está sendo feito não irá trazer nenhum registro de nome **Triplo** já que ele não está presente na tabela de disponibilidade pois está sendo usado o **FULL OUTER JOIN**, recomendo realizar a pesquisa iniciando na tabela de tipos e utilizar usar o **LEFT JOIN** da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT 
    D.DATA, 
    T.NOME,
    COALESCE(SUM(OCUPADO),0) OCUPADO,
    COALESCE(SUM(MANUTENCAO),0) MANUTENCAO
FROM 
    TIPOS T
LEFT JOIN 
    DISPONIBILIDADE D ON D.TIPO = T.ID
GROUP BY 
    D.DATA, T.NOME
```

Comment: Eu tentei fazer assim também, mas ainda não pega os dados da tabela **tipos**.

Comment: Eu vi que sua *query* realmente funciona para MySQL, porém aqui no Firebird não... Fiz o teste [aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4ef8/1).

Comment: Não sei se vai ser possível associar/agrupar essas duas tabelas pela data, já que a tabela de disponibilidade não possui registro do tipo Triplo

Comment: Paulo, eu criei novas tabelas no Firebird e coloquei os mesmos dados, o problema ocorre quando faço filtro de datas, vou editar a pergunta, pois preciso deste filtro.

Comment: Não sai as datas por conta que não tem registro com ID = 2 fiz os teste aqui e se tem registro com o id = 2 ele sai com as datas...